# I want to select my balance "column" From user table laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I'm a beginner in laravel framework,I am in the course of developing an API,and I want to select from users table balance of user when I get her Id in api So I do what I found in documentations in my contoller and i use postman to test my work but always I get a error 
this is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyBalanceController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        # code...
        //  $Ads = ads::all();
        //  return $this->sendResponse($Ads->toArray(), 'Ads read succesfully');
        // This is the name of the column you wish to search
        $input = $request->all();
        $validator =    Validator::make($input, [
            'user_id'=> 'required'
        ] );

        $Cards = User::where('user_id','=', $request->user_id)->pluck('balance')->toArray();
        //$user = Auth::user();
       // $Cards = DB::select('select balance from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);


        return response()->json(['Cards'=>$Cards]);
    }
}
```

this is my modal :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','username','lastname','tel','adress','balance'
    ];
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Add `get()` to your query `User::where()->get()->pluck()->toArray()`

Comment: Whoops, looks like something went wrong. this is the error

Comment: $Cards = User::where('user_id','=', $request->user_id)->get('balance')->pluck('balance')->toArray(); like this ???

Comment: The `get()` method doesn't accept parameters.

Comment: $Cards = User::where('user_id','=', $request->user_id)->get()->pluck('balance')->toArray(); so like this?

Comment: What about the user id. Are you sure that in your users table this field is called user_id and not just id?

Comment: No and I fix this and this what i do  $Cards = User::where('id','=', $request->user_id)->pluck('balance')->toJson(); but also i get a error

Comment: I think my error is in my model i'm sure

Comment: in the model adress is misspelled .. should be address

Comment: Also in your model. the return of **getJWTCustomClaims()**. If you want to return an empty array. you can use **return array();**

Comment: Or **$arr = array();** and then **return $arr;**

Comment: I fix the error now but I get null result

Comment: {
    "Cards": [
        null
    ]
}

Comment: what if you put a dd($Cards); after your query? is it empty?

Answer (score 0):

At first you can go to your .env file and set APP_DEBUG to true so you can see your exceptions when developing your app.

Regarding your problem try

```
$balance = User::findOrFail($request->user_id)->balance;
return response()->json($balance);
```

If no user was found with that id then a 404 HTTP error will be thrown